# NSPredicate Get Date by Interval

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nspredicate

I need to able to get array of date in **5 mins interval, 10 mins interval, daily, monthly and yearly interval** for a stocks. So far I can only come out with this predicate but I'm not sure how am I proceed to implement interval.

```
var datetime =  "2014-07-14T09:00:00:+08:000"
quoteArray = Quote.objectsWhere("date >= %@",datetime)
```

Comment: Please explain your self better, describe what do you want to get

Comment: For example, I need to get 1 year dates with monthly interval of date arrays but I'm not sure how to achieve this

Comment: To get all dates between to dates (like Jan 2015 and Feb 2015), you have to do `date >= dateJan2015 AND date <= dateFeb2015`, but if you want a day granularity when you fetch for a month, you have to add them manually, or do a median yourself. If I remember, there is a `@mean` that you can use, or `@sum` according to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If, given a date, you want to generate the next 12 monthly dates, then use NSCalendar.   Playground was used.

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss:Z"
var ds = "2014-07-14T09:00:00:+0000"
var dt = formatter.dateFromString(ds)  
print( formatter.stringFromDate(dt!))  // just show what we have.

let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)
var monthDates = [NSDate]()
for i in 1...12 {
    let month = calendar?.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Month, value: i, toDate: dt!, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
    print(month!)
    monthDates.append(month!)
}
```

Note that these will one month apart apart, but are not necessarily on nice day or month boundaries.

---

To get 24 hours worth of 10 minute intervals, starting at the given date time:

```
var min10Intervals = [NSDate]()
for i in 1..144 {
    let tenMinute = calendar?.dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Minute, value: i*10, toDate: dt!, options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchStrictly)
    min10Intervals.append(tenMinute!)
}
```

Note that these will 10 minutes apart, but are not necessarily on nice 10 minute boundaries (like 11:10) unless the given date-time is.

If one is filtering or summarizing data and assigning it to intervals, that is a different problem.